# C++ my own class predicate is not working

Tags: c++, class, predicate

I'm a complete newbie at C++. I want to create my own predicate. But the part with bool operator seems to be wrong (at least in my humble opinion). Could someone give me a hint? I don't want to change the overall structure of this idea, I'm just sure I don't understand some details about operator () implementation or something related to classes in c++.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Predicate
{

private:
    int number = 0;

public:
    Predicate() = default;
    Predicate(const int number)
    {
        this->number = number;
    }
    bool operator()(int value) const
    {
        Predicate *pred = new Predicate();
        bool result = pred->operator()(value);
        return result;
    }
};

class Even : public Predicate
{
    bool operator()(int value) const
    {
        return value % 2 == 0;
    }
};

class Negative : public Predicate
{
    bool operator()(int value) const
    {
        return value < 0;
    }
};

int count(const std::vector<int> &elements, const Predicate &predicate)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < elements.size(); ++index)
    {
        if (predicate(elements[index]))
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> elements{-7, 12, -11, 2, 9, -4, -6, 5, 23, -1};
    std::cout << count(elements, Even()) << " " << count(elements, Negative()) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be wrong that an overloaded operator creates an infinite recursion. What is `Predicate *pred = new Predicate(); bool result = pred->operator()(value);` supposed to do?

Comment: You may want to [edit] this question to explain what you want `operator bool()` to actually do.

Comment: Whatever operator bool() is supposed to do it should not allocate `Predicate *pred = new Predicate();` then leak this memory by throwing away the pointer and not freeing it. Not sure why you allocate at all in a `operator bool()`

Comment: Maybe you wanted a pure virtual: `bool operator()(int value) const =0;` and make this an abstract class.

Comment: As others have mentioned you have infinite recursion currently. You create a class derived from `Predicate` which has an operator defined which then defines a new `Predicate` again, and uses the `()` operator which .... round and round. One solution: get rid of the definition of operator () in your base class and make it a pure virtual member: `bool operator() (int value) const = 0;`. Let the derived class define and perform the operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is:

- define `Predicate` as an abstract type,
- implements different versions of it.

`Predicate` as an abstract type:

```
class Predicate {
  public:
    virtual bool operator(int v) const = 0;
};
```

Implementing (realising) a given `Predicate`:

```
class IsNegative : public Predicate { // means IsNegatives are Predicates
  public:
    virtual bool operator(int v) const { return v<0; } // realisation of the operator
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you.